# wp theme.. Could not create directory

Tags: themes, errors, directory, installation

Could anyone help me with this please?
I am trying to install my wp theme Recital (it came out quite recently), but when I upload the zip and press install, it says Could not create directory...

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: This is probably a permissions issue, is your 'wp-content' directory writable?

Comment: Have you previously installed themes from the same vendor on this particular WordPress installation? Sometimes, vendors give you a link to a zip that needs to be unzipped as it contains other items that may not be part of the theme file structure. Have you checked in the zip folder to see that it follows the appropriate conventions?

Answer (score 2):

If you can log into your host with SSH or FTP, it's an easy fix. Like the comments said before, check your permissions for the Wordpress directory. For example, if you check the hosting directory with `ls -al` (typically `/var/www`, as on DigitalOcean), they should look something like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 17:00 wordpress
```

That means both the user and group has write permissions set.  To make sure those are set correctly, you can use this command on the directory:

```
sudo chmod ug+w wordpress
```

Also, make sure the user and group ownership is set correctly.  In the above example, the server daemon is run under the `www-data` user and group (it could also be `httpd`).  To set the directory's ownership to `www-data` you can run the command `chown` like this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress
```

If you're using an FTP client, try right-clicking the `wordpress` directory and using its Permissions functionality to set the permissions and ownership (will vary from FTP app to FTP app).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

CentOS7 or Ubuntu 16

---

#### 1.

WordPress uses `ftp` to install **themes** and **plugins**.
So the `ftpd` should have been configured to create-directory

```
vim /etc/pure-ftpd.confg
```

and if it is **no** then should be **yes**

```
# Are anonymous users allowed to create new directories?
AnonymousCanCreateDirs       yes
```

lastly

```
sudo systemctl restart pure-ftpd
```

[image]

#### 2.

Maybe there is an ownership issue with the parent directories.
Find the Web Server user name and group name if it is **Apache Web Server**

```
apachectl -S
```

it will print

```
...
...
User: name="apache" id=997
Group: name="apache" id=1000
```

*on Ubuntu it is*

> User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
>   Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used

then

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache directory-name
```

[image]

#### 3.

Sometimes it is because of directories permissions.
So try

```
sudo chmod -R 755 directory-name
```

in some cases `755` does not work. (It should & I do not no why) so try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 directory-name
```

[image]

#### 4.

Maybe it is because of php safe mode.
So turn it **off** in the root of your domain

```
vim php.ini
```

then add

```
safe_mode = Off
```

[image]

NOTE:
For not entering **FTP** username and password each time installing a theme we can configure WordPress to use it directly by adding

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

to the **wp-config.php** file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for MAC & localhost, the solution is easy. Go to your Wordpress directory & change the permissions.

**HOW?**
Clicking right button, more information (command+i), Sharing & Permissions.

Activate all for reading & writing for all users (including *everyone*) in all the folders mentioned above.

the *wp-config.php* **script**,
the *wp-content* **folder**, the *wp-content/plugins* **folder**, the *wp-conent/themes* **folder**,
the *wp-includes* **folder**.

Finally, in the *wp-admin* **folder** activate the permits for reading & writing for the admin and yourself (do not activate permit for *everyone* here!)

Tutorial (in spanish) here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJXljTtqI3A

(For those not speaking Spanish, it can also be helpful, its very visual)

Hope this is useful
xx